# Anybody runs Flash Media Server on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, flash-media-server

I want to use `RTMFP` in Adobe's **Flash Media Interactive Server 4** and host in the cloud.

- What results do you have running FMS 3.5/4 in Amazon EC2?
- Do you use Windows/Linux version?

Comment: Mirezko where you actually able to try to out?

Comment: @Saad it shows, that it is more expensive than Influxis, for startup project like ours, so I didn't try... and we ended up with enterprise version for P2P capability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I am going for [***INFLUXIS***](http://www.influxis.com/).

Comment: and this answer very much look like advertisment, but after 5 months, I really couldn't find better solution...